# R- Extracting number from string in a column

Tags: r

My data is stored in this format

```
District Andamans (01), Andaman & Nicobar Islands (35)
```

in all the rows of a single column. I would like to add them to a new column in this format 01-35 using R. I tried using

```
 as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(abc$District, '\\d+')))
```

but it gives me seperated ioutputs which I can not load in a single column of the same length(1180 columns) as the column for my data above (590 columns).

Answer (score 3):

If we need in a specific format, use `lapply` to loop through the `list` (as `str_extract_all` returns a `list` and `paste`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(abc$District, "\\d+"), function(x) paste(x, collapse="-"))
#[1] "01-35"
```

#### data

```
abc <- structure(list(District = "District Andamans (01), Andaman & Nicobar Islands (35)"), .Names = "District", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = "data.frame")
```